# Connecting VS Code to Github via SSH results in SSH error

Tags: git, github, ssh

Trying my hand at setting up VS Code and connecting it to my GitHub repo.

I have followed GitHubs documentation https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh and have a key.

The key has been added to my GitHub account.

I'm also following this tutorial https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh that asks you to connect via the Visual Studio Code Remote - SSH Extension.

After CTRL+SHIFT+P and selecting "Remote-SSH: Connect to a host" and entering git@github.com I am presented with the following error:

```
"Could not establish a connection to "github.com". The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe"
```

I have limited experience with SSH and nothing I'm reading seems to be helping me out. I've read a few Q&A here at SO though again nothing seems to be getting me away from this one error message.

How do I connect to GitHub, via SSH so that I can leverage all git commands and push/sync to my remote repo?

I've also tried the following hosts:

- git@github.com:DarrenWainwright (my username)

  - Could not establish connection to "github.com:DarrenWainwright"
- git@github.com:DarrenWainwright/VSCodePlayground (repo)

  - Failed to write install script to path...
- git@github.com:DarrenWainwright/VSCodePlayground.git (git file)

  - Failed to write install script to path

Comment: I guess you need to provide a full repository URL, not just git@github.com ?

Comment: @Martin - thanks. Just tried it, similar issues. Updated the Q.

Answer (score 2):

You're using an extension that isn't designed for this purpose.

The extension you're using is designed for logging to a remote server which you control and editing code on that system.  For example, you'd use this extension if you were using a Mac laptop but needed to log into a remote Linux development VM that contained your source code.

Since GitHub doesn't provide a development VM, only cloning and fetching using the Git protocol over SSH, you need to use functionality designed for that.  You'd want to either use the command line to clone and set up your repository or use an SSH remote (e.g., `git@github.com:DarrenWainwright/VSCodePlayground.git`) with the [documentation outlined here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol).

Comment: Thank you. Appears I have a misunderstanding of what I am doing :) 

I come from a Visual Studio world and a nice GUI that takes care of much of my needs. Cloning is easy enough but how do you setup VS Code to use GitHub as SCM where I can push/pull/sync to GitHub? I try a git clone along with my SSH URL and then get errors "Permission denied (publicKey) - my brain hurts.

Comment: If the clone is failing with `Permission denied (publickey)` at the command line, then your key isn't properly registered with GitHub.  There are a lot of other answers explaining how to get that fixed (other than by using HTTPS).  You should also be able to do `ssh -Tv git@github.com` and get a message about having successfully authenticated when things are set up properly.

Comment: Thanks again. I have a feeling I've pretty much mucked things up to a point I need to remove everything and start again.